# Dividing reflectance values of Sentinel-2 sets of bands using rasterio

Tags: python, remote-sensing, rasterio, multi-band

I need to divide the reflectance values of a Sentinel-2 sets of bands. To do this, I have to divide each band by 10000 when I read in the band to write the stack.  I have an example of my code snippet below.  I will know that I got the right answer when the dtype has changed to a float type from a uint type.  It's a compression thing, which isn't necessary to understand but the change of dtype will show that the code is correct.

```
    #But this time, divide all reflectance values by 10000 when you supply the
    #individual bands' arrays to the write function of the new layer stack.
    #This is because surface reflectance values for the Sentinel 2 data are
    #scaled by 10000. So, a value of 5000 in one of the bands (uint16 dtype)
    #is actually a reflectance value of 0.5 (i.e. 5000/10000).


    stackedD2 = rasterio.open (
        os.path.join(outputDataDir, 'stackedD2.tiff'), mode = 'w',
        driver = 'GTiff',
        height = b1.height,
        width = b1.width,
        count = len(inlistB),
        dtype = b1.dtypes[0],
        crs = b1.crs,
        transform=b1.transform    
        )


    stackedD2.write((b1.read()[0]/10000), 1)
    stackedD2.write((b2.read()[0]/10000), 2)
    stackedD2.write((b3.read()[0]/10000), 3)
    stackedD2.write((b4.read()[0]/10000), 4)
    stackedD2.close()

    stackedD2 = rasterio.open(os.path.join(outputDataDir, 'stackedD2.tif'), mode = 'r')
```

I'm mostly unsure on where to put the "/10000" part in the code. I'm using python code with the rasterio module.

Comment: Seems like you're setting the dtype In `rasterio.open(...)` to that of raster b1, which is uint16, while you'd need to specify a valid float datatype (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) and, perhaps, explicitly change the raster's datatype to accomodate float values (https://stackoverflow.com/q/57245971/18309711)

Comment: I've been informed by my professor that I don't need manually change the data type becasue the uint will change to float when the division by 10000 occurs